# Keras backend gradients in lambda layer rise AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dtype'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-lambda

My neural network is supposed to calculate the gradients of the output of a dense layer with respect to some coordinates that are passed in an Input layer. I use the [keras backend function](https://keras.rstudio.com/reference/k_gradients.html) in a [lambda layer](https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/lambda/). I get this error at the beginning of the training

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

This is the code with random numbers that can be used to reproduce the error:

```
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.models import *
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Lambda
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras import backend as k
from keras.models import *

coords = np.random.rand(1000,5,3)
forces = np.random.rand(1000,5,3)
input= np.random.rand(1000,17)

inputs_1    = Input((input.shape[1]))
inputs_2    = Input((coords.shape[1],coords.shape[2]))
initializer = 'normal'
dense_1 = Dense(1000, kernel_initializer=initializer, activation='relu')(inputs_1)
dense_2 = Dense(1, kernel_initializer=initializer, activation="relu")(dense_1)
out=Lambda(lambda x:k.gradients(x[0],x[1]),output_shape=(5,3))([dense_2,inputs_2])
model=Model(inputs=[inputs_1,inputs_2], outputs=out)

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0001),loss=keras.losses.mean_absolute_error) 

model.summary()
history=model.fit([input,coords],forces, 
          batch_size=1,
          epochs=100,
          verbose=2,
          validation_split=0.1)
```

This is the summary where I get `multiple` as output shape of the last layer:

```
Model: "model_2"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 input_9 (InputLayer)           [(None, 17)]         0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 dense_8 (Dense)                (None, 1000)         18000       ['input_9[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
 dense_9 (Dense)                (None, 1)            1001        ['dense_8[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
 input_10 (InputLayer)          [(None, 5, 3)]       0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 lambda_4 (Lambda)              multiple             0           ['dense_9[0][0]',                
                                                                  'input_10[0][0]']               
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 19,001
Trainable params: 19,001
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Can someone find out where is the error on the use of `k.gradients` in my code?

Comment: What is the version of numpy? Problem may exists with numpy `1.21.3`, downgrade to `1.19.5` works. Thanks!

Comment: I'm testing my code on Google Colab, the numpy version is 1.19.5 and the keras version is 2.7.0